# How can I modify my __repr__ to respresent correctly?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-itertools, built-in, repr

My `__repr__` method works fine using objects created in it's class, but with objects that were created with the help of importing a library and using methods from it, it only represented the memory address...

```
from roster import student_roster #I only got the list if students from here 
import itertools as it

class ClassroomOrganizer:
  def __init__(self):
    self.sorted_names = self._sort_alphabetically(student_roster)

  def __repr__(self):
    return f'{self.get_combinations(2)}'

  def __iter__(self):
    self.c = 0
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    if self.c < len(self.sorted_names):
      x = self.sorted_names[self.c]
      self.c += 1
      return x
    else: 
      raise StopIteration

  def _sort_alphabetically(self,students):
    names = []
    for student_info in students:
      name = student_info['name']
      names.append(name)
    return sorted(`your text`names)

  def get_students_with_subject(self, subject):
    selected_students = []
    for student in student_roster:
      if student['favorite_subject'] == subject:
        selected_students.append((student['name'], subject))
    return selected_students
  
  def get_combinations(self, r):
    return it.combinations(self.sorted_names, r)

a = ClassroomOrganizer()
# for i in a:  
#   print(i)


print(repr(a))
```

I tried displaying objects that don't rely on anther library, and they dispayed properly.

Comment: "t only represented the memory address..." it *is* displaying properly. Your `__repr__` simply provides the string representation of `self.get_combinations(2)`, which is equivalent to `it.combinations(self.sorted_names, r)`. So why did you **expect** anything other than the string representation of an `itertools.combinations` object? That is *what you coded it to give you*. What were you *expecting*?

Comment: I expected the values computed by itertools.combinations, not the memory adress, what do I need to change?

Comment: Did you *see* what `print(it.combinations.self.sorted_names, r)` gives you?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was facing was linked to me not understanding the nature of the object. `itertools.combinations` is an iterable, and in order to represent the values stored I needed to either:

1. unpack it inside a variable like:

   ```
   def get_combinations(self, r):
       *res, = it.combinations(self.sorted_names, r)
       return res
   ```
2. Iter through it inside a loop and leave the original code intact like

   ```
   for i in a.get_combinations(2):
       print(i)
   ```

I prefer the second solution

Comment: The second solution does not create a valid `__repr__` since it doesn't provide a string. Note, `*res,  = it.combinations(...)` should just be `res = list(it.combinations(...))`